# PHP PhantomJS doesn't work on web server

Tags: php, phantomjs, php-phantomjs

Have the next problem: installed php phantomjs on MAMP. Made all using instructions from here: [enter link description here](http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/4.0/)

Everything is ok... Then i copied all my site files to my web hosting site folder and nothing worked. Made a var_dump of response and saw that:

> object(JonnyW\PhantomJs\Http\Response)#156 (8) { ["headers"]=> NULL ["status"]=> NULL ["content"]=> NULL ["contentType"]=> NULL ["url"]=> NULL ["redirectURL"]=> NULL ["time"]=> NULL ["console"]=> NULL }

Why it doesn't work, why all is NULL?
My code is:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client;

$client = Client::getInstance();

$request = $client->getMessageFactory()->createRequest('http://jonnyw.me', 'GET');

$response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();

var_dump($response);

$client->send($request, $response);


echo $response->getContent();
```

Comment: Can you login to your server via SSH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likley things is if it's shared hosting, they will more than probably not allow you to execute arbitrary executables... i.e. the executable in `~/bin/phantomjs`

To execute non-standard i.e. user installed stuff, you'll need a VPS or Dedicated server.

Comment: thanx, and is any solution of this problem?

Comment: @ArtyomSosonko Yes, buy a VPS from one of many hosting providers: https://www.digitalocean.com/ or http://flops.ru

Comment: I've got a VPS but my problem persist. What configuration I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was about executable downloaded by composer, so following [issue #86](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs/issues/86) I put this on my code:

`$client->getEngine()->setPath('/usr/bin/phantomjs');`

So now I'm using default binaries and works great.